# how to get data to datatable using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, datatable

I am trying to bind datasource of dropdownlist to datatable, column of gridview show 'has error' & no data is displayed , I am wondering what's problem of my linq query.

data in my datatable like this

> ```
> '26/12/2012 0:00:00',
> '1/1/2012 0:00:00',
> '1/5/2013 0:00:00',
> '1/7/2013 0:00:00',
> '4/5/2014 0:00:00
> ```

error table:

[image]

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["DT"];
        var date = from q in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where q.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year == int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())
                   select q;

        GridView1.DataSource = date;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Is the column really of type `DateTime` or `String`? Then you need to parse it: `DateTime.Parse(q.Field<string>("Date")).Year`

Comment: the datetype of column is datetime

Comment: So what error do you get? Add `ToList` to `date` then you're seeing it earlier. Also, _"column of gridview show 'has error'"_ is highly misleading, i assume that this is a column in the grid that refers to an "error-column" in your table. So it's not related to a possible error in your query, is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter in the picture it shows two rows so the where works somewhat. Isn't it a projection problem?

Comment: @rene: so is the issue that you get rows but no columns? You need to show us the aspx of the GridView as well.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the issue but I edited the post so the screenshot is now embedded...

Comment: can you try `select new { date = q["Date"] };` instead of `select q;`

Comment: "column of gridview show 'has error'" it means the problem in photo(hyperlink)

Comment: Could you show the aspx page then.

Comment: Are you sure there _is_ an error? If you get no error message, it may well be that the datatable really contains a `bool` column named `HasErrors`. Please, post the aspx definition of the gridview, the code that creates this table and the exact exception message+callstack you get when debugging

Comment: if i add `select new { date = q["Date"] };` instead of `select q;` ,error message prompt `The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.`, but i am sure my datatable has data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HasErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.haserrors.aspx) is a property of `DataRow`, i think you need to materialize the query to somewhat that contains the columns you want to show. Either use `CopyToDataTable` to create a `DataTable` from the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` or create a list of an anonymous type:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["DT"];
var filteredRows = from q in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where q.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year == int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())
                   select q;
GridView1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```